# how to set value in anchor tag in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

could you please tell me how to set value in anchor tag  in xslt ? I have two anchor tag .I want to set value in that

for `abc` I want href ="http://abc/pqr.com"
for `ddd` I want href ="http://india/pqrfff.com"

can I use choose or othere wise ..or is there any thing like `key` `value` pair in xslt ? can we make object in xslt ?

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvA
**input**

```
 <col>
        <s>
            <name>abc</name>
        </s>
        <s>
             <name>dddd</name>
        </s>
    </col>
```

**expected output**

```
 <h3><a href="http://abc/pqr.com">abc</a></h3>
   <h3><a href="http://india/pqrfff.com">dddd</a></h3>
```

Comment: Since you have separate URLs for each href attribute, you can't simply iterate and assign different url's to your anchor elements. If you have an extension in your XSLT processor, which supports writing code in another programming language, you should be able to create a static Map with `key` as value of name element and `value` as the corresponding href attribute.

Comment: can we make `object` in xslt ?? mean I create a global object with key and value ..using that key I will get value from that object ?

Comment: could you please give example

Comment: could you please share your code

Comment: There is no inbuilt facility to create objects in XSLT. What XSLT processor are you using and does it support extension functions? If yes, it is possible to write a Map and retrieve values for href attribute from that Map

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to keep "name / url" pairs in an external file, say *Links.xml*, something like this:

```
<links>
  <link>
    <name>abc</name>
    <url>http://abc/pqr.com</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <name>dddd</name>
    <url>http://india/pqrfff.com</url>
  </link>
</links>
```

Then in the main XSL file you can load this file:

```
<xsl:variable name="links" select="document('links.xml')"/>
```

The last thing is to generate output `a` tags, according to source data in each `col/s` element.
Take the text part of the tag directly from the source `name` tag
and the content of `href` attribute look up in `$links`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href" select="@links/link[@name=name]/url"/>
```

**Another concept**

Extend your XML file (include `href` tag along with `name`). Then you would not need any external document.

Comment: you can also put the contents of the <links> tag directly in the xsl:variable, instead of referencing an external file.